# OS X not reopening old windows of Adobe Acrobat on restart

Tags: macos, adobe-acrobat

When I restart my Mac and have it remember the old windows, it is able to do this correctly for all applications except Adobe Acrobat 10.1.10

I have checked if Acrobat is storing its old windows correctly in /Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro.savedState/ and...amazingly it does! I can see all my old windows in windows.plist.

So now I am really confused, I have no idea why only Acrobat is not able to reopen its windows even though its saving its data correctly. Is it a Mac issue? An Acrobat issue? I imagine it's an Acrobat issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried trashing the SavedState folder & trying again? I've seen them go weird on apps before now & clearing has usually set them straight.

Comment: There is also a Preferences option to reopen the documents at the place you left it.